# strange left margin appears in firefox

Tags: html, css, margin

take a look at this site : [IUT Wiki](http://wiki.iut.ac.ir)

A strange margin appears at the left side of the whole html and it only appears in Firefox.

Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: you have an element with a huge `margin-left` somewhere

Comment: no, at least not what appears in firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to solve the cause of the problem:

you have in the css:

```
ul#f-list {
    width: 1025px;
}
```

change it to 100%

Comment: @ZoltanToth yes, I changed it to overflow-x.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, it just a method to go around the actual problem.

Comment: @starcorn: You're right, I edited my answer.

Comment: your right that solved it! It's funny that other browsers ignored it but FF didn't.